# Android Intent filter URL path including #

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-intent, path, prefix

I need to filter out URLs with an intent filter, that point to an appengine webinterface, so I can open them in the corresponding app if the user has it installed.

The URL is like that: `http://my-domain.de/#/routes/<id>` where `<id>` is a long. The problem is, that android seems to not like the `#` in the url, as this should do the trick:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="my-domain.de"
                android:pathPrefix="/#/routes/"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

But he actually does not respond to an url like that. If I remove the `#` and make it `android:pathPrefix="/routes/"` it works in android, but that is not the appspot URL.

any help/tips how to solve this? Or is the only way to leave the Prefix out and check in the app if it matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any help/tips how to solve this?

You can't solve it using the `<intent-filter>`. The `#` and material to the right of it are not considered to be part of the path (or anything else) for `Intent` resolution.

> Or is the only way to leave the Prefix out and check in the app if it matches?

Yes, or somehow change the server to remove or move the `#`. I have never used Google App Engine, so I have no idea if this is possible or not.